# Responsive Bootstrap Button

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 and can't seem to get the spacing between the button right when on iphone.
https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css

```
  <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-auto">

                            <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Log In" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto">

                            <button class="btn btn-info " @onclick="@(() => navManager.NavigateTo("signup"))">Register</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <button class="btn btn-warning  " @onclick="@(() => navManager.NavigateTo("forgotpassword"))">Reset Password</button>

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

This is how it looks on iphone. 
There is no spacing between the button when it breaks to another row.
[image]

This is how it looks on Desktop, which is acceptable
[image]

Comment: Please insert the code with the form. Please insert the code with the form. The buttons seem to be influenced by the classes you give the form elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit of `CSS` is required and that all!

Below `347px` screen size is where your button is not working correctly

giving `btn-danger` CSS attribute that when screen get's below `347px`, `margin-top` will be applied to it as `css` style.

```css
 @media screen and (max-width: 347px) {
   .btn-warning {
     margin-top: 10px;
   }
 }
```

```html
 <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-auto">

     <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Log In" />
   </div>
   <div class="col-auto">

     <button class="btn btn-info " @onclick="@(() => navManager.NavigateTo(" signup"))">Register</button>
   </div>
   <div class="col-auto">
     <button class="btn btn-warning" @onclick="@(() => navManager.NavigateTo(" forgotpassword"))">Reset Password</button>

   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add some `top-margin` to it, like

```
<div class="col-auto">
    <button class="btn btn-warning  " @onclick="@(() => navManager.NavigateTo("forgotpassword"))" style="margin-top:10px">Reset Password</button>
</div>
```